# Why my logo disappears when resizing my browser in firefox

Tags: image, firefox, responsive-design

I am currently building a standard html web page.  I have a logo in the top right corner.  When I resize my browser the logo disappears.  It works like it should in all other browsers.

It seems to disappear when my browser is small enough to convey mobile versions and navigation stops being inline and is displayed block

i dont think its an html problem, as it works in other browsers so here is my css for the image.

```
img#logo {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #111111;
  max-width: 100%;   
  width: auto;   
  height: auto;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a min-width. Change 300 to whatever works best. You can also use a min-width %. Like, 20%.

```
img#logo {
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

edit:

Ok, now I see the real problem, its this

```
img#logo {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #111111;
  max-width: 100%;   
  width: auto;   // width auto...
  height: auto;  // height auto..
}
```

please change those to an actual value so you don't rely on varying browser defaults.

```
img#logo {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #111111;
  max-width: 100%;   // and you can remove this line
  width: 100%;   
  height: 100%;
}
```

If that still does not work for you. Try removing the height line all together.

Comment: This doesn't work :( it just makes my image smaller when the browser is at full size

Comment: Now the image takes half the page, with and without the height attribute.  Sorry for the silly questions